# Using grep to get src attribute from html file

Tags: regex, grep

How to chain grep to match images between double quotation marks?

```
$ cat final.html | grep -Po 'src=\".*?\"'
src="Remix-OS-Download-Option.png"
src="VMSetup1.png"
src="VMSetup2.png"
src="VMSetup3_001.png"
src="VMSetup4.png"
src="VMSetup5.png"
src="VMSetup6.png"
```

**Expected result:**

```
Remix-OS-Download-Option.png
VMSetup1.png
...
VMSetup6.png
```

Comment: no need to use `cat`... just use `grep -Po 'regexp' file`... and using html/xml parser would be better choice than using regex

Comment: @Sundeep you're right i think i have developed a habit of cating everything and for sure using a html/xml parser is better but this was only a quick hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will be helpful. As we are using perl regular expression here you can check demo [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/MqrGyr/1)

**Pipe your Command with:** `grep -Po '="\K[^"]+'`

**Regex:** `="\K[^"]+`

> **1.** `="\K` this will match `="` and `\K` will reset the current match.
>
> **2.** `[^"]+` match all except `"`

**Complete command:**

`cat final.html | grep -Po 'src=\".*?\"' | grep -Po '="\K[^"]+'`

***Optionally you can try this one:*** `cat final.html | grep -Po 'src="\K[^"]+'`

Comment: Good use of `\K` ++. Instead of 2 `grep`, it can be done in a single `grep` as `... | grep -oP 'src="\K[^"]+'`